# Performance of BeanUtils vs. ReflectionToStringBuilder (for use in Bean classes)

Tags: java, performance, reflection, javabeans, apache-commons-beanutils

I have a large number of Java bean classes in my web application, and I am trying to find a simple way to implement the `toString()` methods in these beans. The `toString()` method would be used for logging throughout the application, and should print the attribute-value pairs of all attributes in the bean.

I am trying out two alternatives:
1. `BeanUtils.describe()` (Apache commons-beanutils)
2. `ReflectionToStringBuilder.toString()` (Apache commons-lang)

Since this is a web application expected to have high traffic, the implementation has to be lightweight and should not impact performance. (Memory use, processor use, etc are main considerations).

I'd like to know which of these performs better according the criteria mentioned above. As far as I know, reflection is a heavy operation, but more details and insight into both these options would help me choose the optimal solution.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We use `ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString()` in our objects' `toString()` methods. We have not had any issues running like this in a production environment. Granted, we rarely use the `toString()` method.

We also use `BeanUtils.describe()`, but for another purpose. `BeanUtils` uses `PropertyUtilsBean` which keeps an internal cache of beans for which it has performed introspection. It would seem that this would give it a performance advantage over the other, but a little poking around in the reflectionToString source and it seems that since it ultimately relies on the implementation of `java.lang.Class`, caching comes into play there as well.

Either looks like a viable choice, but `BeanUtils.describe()` will return a Map of properties where reflectionToString will return a formatted String. I guess it depends on what you want to do with the output.

I would suggest that if your application is heavily dependent on calling `toString()` on your objects, having a specific implementation might be more beneficial.

Comment: "having a specific implementation might be more beneficial": that was my third alternative, and the one we use in most existing applications. Although time-consuming, this may be the optimal solution after all!

Comment: @jt: In my case, I use the `toString()` method for logging(LOGGER) purpose. Is it better to use `ReflectionToStringBuilder.toString()` than `BeanUtils.describe()`?

Comment: @omega: The advantage of `ReflectionToStringBuilder.toString()` (RTSB) over `Map.toString()` - which is what I suppose you are ultimately using after calling `BeanUtils.describe()` (BU) - is that `RTSB` will dive deep into your objects and produce a `String` representation of them. `BU` is likely to just call `toString()` on each property in your object. This may result in `Object.toString()`'s implementation unless you have built out each of those properties' `toString()` methods. Realistically, you could avoid implementing `toString()` methods and just use `RTSB` directly when you need it.

Comment: @jt: Besides what you wrote to @omega, and like you stated, there's a possibility that `BeanUtils` is faster.. I'm currently using the `ReflectionToStringBuilder` with a `ToStringStyle` to generate a diagram (with the help of GraphViz) of what i'm doing.
However, I know that it slows it down, it would be cool if one could have a `ToStringStyle` or something else, that avoided the need to do reflection everytime, and would cache a pre defined number of classes, for speeding up the process. (I hate boilerplate)

Answer (score 10):

Personally, I prefer to generate the toString() method using Eclipse/IntelliJ and then modify it as necessary (only include important fields).

Right click -> Source -> Generate toString().  Select fields.  Done.

1. It takes less time than even writing the Builder code.
2. It will execute faster.
3. It doesn't use permgen space (reflection can tend to eat up permgen)

That's the path I would go if you're concerned about performance.

Comment: It looks like the version of Eclipse we have at work does not have this feature. I'll have to settle with writing the methods by hand.

Comment: I believe they added it in Galileo.  There are also lots of plugins you can find that will handle it for you too!

Answer (score 2):

Be careful, as this is reflection based it will be slow.

In a recent web project our Base entity toString() method was ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(this)

This method is called in hibernate during save (via Spring Data JPA respository). We have quite a large object tree with nested lists, leading to a large in memory and CPU hit during save.

It almost sank the project.

Comment: Could it be possible that the hog was coming from the fact that theobjects was JPA entity? (doing hibernate magic while generating toString?)

Answer (score -1):

Just use code generator in your IDE to generate toString() method. This way you will avoid the overhead caused by using reflections. In real production system your toString() method can be called very often (100/sec) causing garbage collector to work hard and pause your JVM. These pauses can be seconds or tens of seconds.

Comment: You've just repeated an existing answer.