# Apache beanutils lock

Tags: java, multithreading, apache-commons-beanutils

One of my production application is getting a large number of threads blocked because of

```
Waiting for Monitor Lock on org/apache/commons/beanutils/WeakFastHashMap@0x000000000E8ECF28
```

Beanutils uses WeakHashMap to manage mapping of converters and the entries in the map are cleared when the garbage collector runs. The code within method WeakFastHashMap.put() is synchronized on **this** and seems that is causing the threads to block.

```
at org/apache/commons/beanutils/WeakFastHashMap.put(WeakFastHashMap.java:249(Compiled Code)) 
at org/apache/commons/beanutils/ConvertUtilsBean.register(ConvertUtilsBean.java:873(Compiled Code)) 
at org/apache/commons/beanutils/ConvertUtilsBean.register(ConvertUtilsBean.java:786(Compiled Code)) 
at org/apache/commons/beanutils/ConvertUtilsBean.registerArrayConverter(ConvertUtilsBean.java:781(Compiled Code)) 
at org/apache/commons/beanutils/ConvertUtilsBean.registerArrays(ConvertUtilsBean.java:745(Compiled Code)) 
at org/apache/commons/beanutils/ConvertUtilsBean.register(ConvertUtilsBean.java:605(Compiled Code))
```

This happens randomly and causes high cpu and reduces the time interval between gc cycles. What would be the best way to handle this.

Beanutils version used is 1.8.0. The line of code that generates this is:

```
BeanUtilsBean.getInstance().getConvertUtils().register(false, false, 0);
```

The other frameworks used in the project are Jersey 1.8 and spring 3.1 and hibernate 4.2.

Comment: Can you provide more info, e.g. what application frameworks you're using, how you're creating the `ConvertUtilsBean`, are you storing the `ConvertUtilsBean` you create anywhere? Etc.

Comment: Added to the question.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is possibly due to the invocation of register method in each thread of the application, while it should be enough to call register once per classloader thread.

Check this similar topic for reference: [Performance of BeanUtils vs. ReflectionToStringBuilder (for use in Bean classes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5656843/performance-of-beanutils-vs-reflectiontostringbuilder-for-use-in-bean-classes).

We had same issue and so far this is the only root cause we have been able to identify.